# Overriding or Intercepting Camel Logging

Tags: apache-camel

An existing application uses Camel logging (bog the "log()" DSL, and also the Log component.

We would like to either intercept or override so that every log message also logs out a specific Header value (e.g. x-correlation-id=ABC-123)

What is a good, idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at MDC logging - and its called something else in slf4j.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, The Camel LogListener, mentioned in the answer below looks like a great solution. Is that better than MDC logging (assuming the values we want are in the Headers of the message)?

Comment: That is very good too, the LogListener is a Camel specific thing, where as MDC is more general. Use the LogListener if its only from the Camel Log EIP and Log component you need this.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, If I use MDC for Camel logging, do I need to use the Camel-generated "breadcrumbId" as the correlation id? Looks like if I want to log an arbitrary Camel header, I need to use the LogListener too?

Comment: Ah! I think I'd need to create a processor (or equivalent) and that is where I'd put the header into the MDC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Camel supports pluggable [`LogListener`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/LogListener.java) since version `2.19.0`. This is pretty powerful, because its method `onLog`, which is invoked right before logging, have instances of `Exchange`, `CamelLogger` and message. You can customize the message there with almost no limitations.

**Implementation of LogListener:**

```
public class MyLogListener implements LogListener {
    @Override
    public String onLog(Exchange exchange, CamelLogger camelLogger, String message) {
        return String.format("%s: %s", exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.CORRELATION_ID), message);
    }
}
```

**LogListener registration:**

```
getContext().addLogListener(new MyLogListener());
```

If you are using Apache Camel version `2.21.0` and newer, you dont need register it to context, because it is looked up in Registry, so annotating `MyLogListener` as `@Bean` is enough.